# how do I delete multiple versions in an app on google cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I deploy a project I get this error

`INVALID_ARGUMENT: Your app may not have more than 15 versions. Please delete one of the existing versions before trying to create a new version.`

I also went to versions on google cloud and tried to delete it manually but it says you can not delete a version with traffic shares.

Please help, any advice are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to keep one version (latest maybe?) and then migrate all traffic to it with the ["Split Traffic" link here](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions), away from all the other versions you want to delete.

Then you will be able to select and delete those versions since they no longer handle traffic.

Finally you deploy the new version (in fact you could do that as soon as you deleted enough versions to no longer see that error) and, if needed, migrate traffic to it.

Also see [gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) for options related to versioning and traffic migration right at deployment time which could help you prevent such situation in the future:

> **`--promote`**
>
> Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic.
>
> True by default. To change the default behavior for your current
>   environment, run:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false
> ```
>
> Overrides the default `promote_by_default` property value for this
>   command invocation. Use `--no-promote` to disable.
>
> **`--stop-previous-version`**
>
> Stop the previously running version when deploying a new version
>   that receives all traffic. Overrides the default
>   `stop_previous_version` property value for this command invocation.
>   Use `--no-stop-previous-version` to disable.
>
> **`--version`=`VERSION`, `-v` `VERSION`**
>
> The version of the app that will be created or replaced by this
>   deployment. If you do not specify a version, one will be generated for
>   you.